# Highcharts - options dump.json

Tags: highcharts

Highcharts recently moved from version 5.0.14 to version 6.0.

The previous API was available at the URLs below:

```
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/option/dump.json
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/option/dump.json
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/object/dump.json
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/object/dump.json
```

However, the new API offers new endpoints using a different format:

```
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tree.json
http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tree.json
```

Where can I find those older API endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tree.json
```

use:

```
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/dump.json
```

Today's link on the Highcharts API web page is not correct.